# android: Fail to connect to camera service on targetSdkVersion change

Tags: android, android-camera

I had following settings in my camera apps manifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Now I changed it to that:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

Problem is: My app is not able to open the camera anymore. This line throws the error:

```
this.camera = Camera.open();
```

Errormessage:

> Fail to connect to camera service

Weird thing, by the way: After starting the app with the new setting, I don't get the camera device running anymore (all other photo apps are crashing at startup too). I have to restart the device to be able to use the camera again.

Can someone help me with that?

my Preview.java class:

```
package net.mt.lib.cc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import net.mt.lib.Tools;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.MemoryInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.ErrorCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.crittercism.app.Crittercism;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;

/**
 *
 * openCamera()
 * onSizeChanged()
 * onLayout()
 * onLayout()
 * surfaceCreated()
 * surfaceChanged()
 * onLayout()
 */
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { // <1>
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceHolder mHolder; // <2>
    public Camera camera; // <3>
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    BaseCameraActivity cameraActivity;
    int l2 = 0, t2 = 0, r2 = 0, b2 = 0;
    int padding = 20;
    PreviewCallback cb;
    private double downscalingFactor = 1;
    // the size of this view. gets set in onMeasure()
    int fullWidth, fullHeight;
    Size bestPictureSize = null;
    Size bestPreviewSize = null;

    private String allResolutions;

    private Context context;

    public Preview(Context context, PreviewCallback callback) {
        super(context);
        this.cb = callback;
        init(context);
    }



    private void init(Context context) {
        setKeepScreenOn(true);
        cameraActivity = (BaseCameraActivity) context;
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);
        this.context = context;
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder(); // <4>
        mHolder.addCallback(this); // <5>
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); // <6>
    }


    public void openCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG,"openCamera()");
        if (this.camera == null) {
            try{
                this.camera = Camera.open();
                this.camera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "error! code:"+error);
                        Toast.makeText(cameraActivity, "Camera error occured: "+error, 8000).show();
                    }
                });
                requestLayout(); // -> onSizeChanged() -> onLayout()
            }catch (Exception e) {
                String errorMessage = "Manufacturer: "+Build.MANUFACTURER+"; Model:"+Build.MODEL+"; Camera: "+this.camera+"; Stacktrace:"+Tools.exception2String(e);
                Log.d(TAG,"error occured: "+errorMessage);
                FlurryAgent.onError("1", errorMessage, "Preview.openCamera()");
                Toast.makeText(cameraActivity, "Uuups, I am sorry! Could not connect to the camera device. Please restart me or your phone.", 8000).show();
                Crittercism.logHandledException(e);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onSizeChanged() "+w+" "+h);
        fullWidth = w;
        fullHeight = h;
        if(fullWidth < fullHeight){ 
            int tmp = fullHeight;
            fullHeight = fullWidth;
            fullWidth = tmp;
            Log.d(TAG,"switched:"+fullWidth+"x"+fullHeight);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"fullSize:"+fullWidth+"x"+fullHeight);
        }
        if(this.camera != null){
            this.setCameraPreviewSize();
            this.setCameraPictureSize();
            if (getChildCount() > 0) {
                final View child = getChildAt(0);
                Log.d(TAG,"r:"+this.getPreviewRight()+" l:"+this.getPreviewLeft()+" b:"+this.getPreviewBottom()+" t:"+this.getPreviewTop());
                child.layout(this.getPreviewLeft(), this.getPreviewTop(), this.getPreviewRight(), this.getPreviewBottom());
                cb.previewReady(getPreviewLeft(), getPreviewTop(), getPreviewRight()-getPreviewLeft(), getPreviewBottom() - getPreviewTop(), getBestPictureSize().width, getBestPictureSize().height, (int) downscalingFactor, allResolutions);
            }
        }

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    private void calcScaledPreviewSize(){       
        int previewWidth = getBestPreviewSize().width;
        int previewHeight = getBestPreviewSize().height;
        float scaledWidth;
        float scaledHeight;

        Log.d(TAG,"preview width: "+previewWidth+", preview height: "+previewHeight);
        Log.d(TAG,"display width: "+fullWidth+", display height: "+fullHeight);
        float previewRatio = (float) previewWidth / (float) previewHeight;
        float displayRatio = (float) fullWidth / (float) fullHeight;

        if(displayRatio >= previewRatio){ // the display is wider then the preview image
            scaledHeight = fullHeight - 2*padding;
            scaledWidth = scaledHeight * previewRatio;
            l2 = (int) (fullWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
            t2 = padding;
            r2 = (int) (fullWidth + scaledWidth) / 2;
            b2 = (int) scaledHeight + padding;

        }else{
            scaledWidth = fullWidth - 2*padding;
            scaledHeight = scaledWidth / previewRatio;
            l2 = padding;
            t2 = (int) (fullHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;
            r2 = (int) scaledWidth + padding;
            b2 = (int) (fullHeight + scaledHeight) / 2;     
        }
    }

    public int getPreviewTop() {
        if(this.t2 == 0){
            this.calcScaledPreviewSize();
        }
        return t2;
    }
    public int getPreviewBottom() {
        if(this.b2 == 0){
            this.calcScaledPreviewSize();
        }
        return b2;
    }
    public int getPreviewLeft() {
        if(this.l2 == 0){
            this.calcScaledPreviewSize();
        }
        return l2;
    }
    public int getPreviewRight() {
        if(this.r2 == 0){
            this.calcScaledPreviewSize();
        }
        return r2;
    }
    public int getPreviewWidth() {
        return this.getPreviewRight()-this.getPreviewLeft();
    }
    public int getPreviewHeight() {
        return this.getPreviewBottom()-this.getPreviewTop();
    }

    private void setCameraPreviewSize() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        if(parameters.getPreviewSize() != this.getBestPreviewSize()){
            parameters.setPreviewSize(this.getBestPreviewSize().width, this.getBestPreviewSize().height);
            this.camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
    }

    private void setCameraPictureSize() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = this.camera.getParameters();
        if(parameters.getPictureSize() != this.getBestPictureSize()){
            parameters.setPictureSize(getBestPictureSize().width, getBestPictureSize().height);
            this.camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onLayout()");
        /*
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0 && this.camera != null) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);
            Log.d(TAG,"r:"+this.getPreviewRight()+" l:"+this.getPreviewLeft()+" b:"+this.getPreviewBottom()+" t:"+this.getPreviewTop());
            child.layout(this.getPreviewLeft(), this.getPreviewTop(), this.getPreviewRight(), this.getPreviewBottom());
            cameraActivity.initOverlay(this.getPreviewLeft(),this.getPreviewTop(),this.getPreviewRight(),this.getPreviewBottom());
        }*/
    }
    public Size getBestPictureSize() {
        if(this.bestPictureSize == null){
            this.calculateOptimalPictureAndPreviewSizes();
        }
        return bestPictureSize;
    }

    public Size getBestPreviewSize() {
        if(this.bestPreviewSize == null){
            this.calculateOptimalPictureAndPreviewSizes();
        }
        return bestPreviewSize;
    }



    // Called once the holder is ready
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { // <7>
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceCreated()");
        try {
            if (this.camera != null) {
                this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);

        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceChanged()");
        if (camera != null) {

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(getBestPreviewSize().width, getBestPreviewSize().height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            cb.onPreviewStart();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { // <14>
        Log.d(TAG,"surfaceDestroyed()");
        if(this.camera != null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.lock();
            camera.release();
            this.camera = null;
        }
    }

    public void releaseCamera(){
        Log.d(TAG,"releaseCamera()");
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }


}
```

The preview is initialised like that (from the main activity):

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG,"onResume()");

        previewLayout.removeAllViews();
        preview = new Preview(this, this);
        previewLayout.addView(preview, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        preview.openCamera();

    }
```

and the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.mc.ccPro"
    android:versionCode="35"
    android:versionName="3.5" >

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ccProActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="net.mc.lib.cc.PreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/set_preferences" >
        </activity>

    </application>

    <supports-screens 
           android:largeScreens="true" 
           android:normalScreens="true" 
           android:smallScreens="true" 
           android:resizeable="true" 
           android:anyDensity="true" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-library android:name="net.mc.lib.cc" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: This usually means that the camera resources are not being released adequately.

Comment: I know. But why is it working properly with targetSdkVersion=8 then?

Comment: You must also post the rest of the code you're using.

Comment: What about the application permissions? Can you post the relevant part from the manifest?

Comment: It's likely something about the camera API has changed between the platform versions.  Try building the API Demos app supplied for the new platform version and see if it works, if it does look at its code (especially compare it to the version supplied for the _old_ SDK versions).  Also consider looking through the android bugs database and see if there is a known issue.

Comment: According to _"all other photo apps are crashing at startup too"_ make sure you call `releaseCamera()` method (e.g. from `onPause()`)

Comment: @a.ch. I cant call camera.releaseCamera(), cause camera == null. the camera object never gets initialised due to the error I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to initialize camera:

```
        Camera camera;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    camera = Camera.open(i);
            }
        }
        if (camera == null)
            camera = Camera.open();
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line into your AndroidManifest as well:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```